# echo unicode does not work with higher codepoints

Tags: echo, unicode

The `echo` command (at least in my environment) supports the `\u` escape followed by a unicode code point in hex.  However it doesn't work on higher codepoints.  For example:

For example, this works:

```
$  echo -ne '\u1234' | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 | xxd
00000000: feff 1234                                ...4
```

But this does not:

```
echo -ne '\ufe70' | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 | xxd

iconv: (stdin):1:1: cannot convert
00000000: feff d7ff                                ....
```

Is there some kind of limitation to the code point?

**EDIT:**

Here is my locale:

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I am using MinGw64 on Windows 10.

Comment: Which locale are you using? `echo -ne '\ufe70' | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-16 | xxd` works alright for me (Debian 10, eo.UTF-8).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I added an edit to the question.

Comment: You are **not** running Unix/Linux then but a layer on top of Windows. I'm not sure this is the right place to ask.

Comment: On a POSIX platform, `echo -ne '\u1234'` results in:`-ne \u1234`.Is this what you intend?